# Python Code review of AES implementation

Tags: aes, implementation

My long term goal is to make a tool similar to [boxcryptor](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en) but first I need to learn how to program and how to properly implement AES.
So far I've been using Python for simplicity but I plan to use a compiled (memory safe) language in the future.
As far as I understand, 'rolling your own crypto' is a bad idea and should be left to experts. I'm experimenting with this precisely because I want to become an experienced cryptographer :)

To my knowledge,

1. The IV doesn't have to remain secret and can be safely stored next to the ciphertext.
2. The data has to be in chunks of 16 bytes
3. The key-length must match that of the cipher
4. Data should be checked for integrity

Now I'm sure my implementation has a lot of flaws so please do correct me.

Right now my biggest problems are:

1. storing the IV, ciphertext and checksum alongside each other and being able to take them appart when decrypting (currently separated using commas and split using text.split(",,,"), 3 comma's in case 1 or 2 comma's appear in the ciphertext?)
2. dividing the data into chunks of 16 bytes (128 bits), specifically padding the last chunk to get equal sized chunks. (e.g 63 chars can be divided into 3 chunks of 16 with some leftover, so I would have to add random data to make a full chunk. How do I get rid of this when decrypting again?)
3. outputting ciphertext and hashes in readable form (currently using hex-encoding)

Comment: I'll answer because you've asked distinct crypto questions in the end, but usually these kind of posts should be asked at Stack Overflow. Hint: first learn crypto, then start programming crypto, not the other way around.

Comment: I removed all the code because 1) code reviews are off topic and 2) your actual questions stand on their own. You can revert the edit if you disagree.

Comment: re: point # 1: it's not really safe to use any small number of characters as a delimiter; if the ciphertext contained ',,,', you have a bug. Try prefixing your cryptogram with the length, or used fixed size messages, so that you don't have to use delimiters.

Comment: @EllaRose Hmm yeah I figured. I used the comma delimiter because I didn't know any other way to split strings at specified lengths. But I've learned that I can actually simply use string1 = string[:16] and string2 = string[16:] to read the first 16 and everything but the first 16 bytes respectively. Since the iv and hmac are of fixed lenght I can just use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. storing the IV, ciphertext and checksum alongside each other and being able to take them appart when decrypting (currently separated using commas and split using text.split(",,,"), 3 comma's in case 1 or 2 comma's appear in the ciphertext?)

The IV is always the same size as the block size, and the block size of AES stays fixed. So you would generally just prefix it to the ciphertext (using 16 bytes, possibly converted to 32 hexadecimal characters).

Your code shows you do not make a clear distinction between bytes and encoding of bytes. Encoding mistakes are one the most common mistakes made by programmers starting cryptography.

> 2. dividing the data into chunks of 16 bytes (128 bits), specifically padding the last chunk to get equal sized chunks. (e.g 63 chars can be divided into 3 chunks of 16 with some leftover, so I would have to add random data to make a full chunk. How do I get rid of this when decrypting again?)

This is called padding, which is not required for all modes of operation (e.g. CTR, counter mode, doesn't require it). For CBC you'd generally use PKCS#7 compatible padding.

> 3. outputting ciphertext and hashes in readable form (currently using hex-encoding)

Hex encoding is fine, but you might wonder why you would do this in the first place. The values will be indistinguishable from random anyway. Base 64 is more efficient if the ciphertext has to be transported.

---

Other notes (*on the removed implementation*):

- SHA-256 is not a Password Based Key Derivation Function, don't use it on passwords (with insufficient entropy);
- `random.randint(0, 0xFF)` is indeed insecure, so why use it? You need a cryptographically secure RNG;
- using a hash as checksum may not be secure, use a (H)MAC or authenticated cipher.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between bytes and the encoding of bytes? Also, how does a SHA512sum differ from (H)MAC?

Comment: The encoding of bytes is simply the *representation* of the byte values in text. If you have a binary interface (file, socket, HTTP connection etc.) you do not need to use hex or base 64 at all. (H)MAC uses  a key in addition to the message input, and protects the construction against length extension attacks. This is required for transport security, where encrypt-than-MAC has become most used (and lately, authenticated cipher modes such as GCM).